# DomainProjectPicker class is obsolete in VSTS 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

What is the alternative for DomainProjectPicker if I want to select a server plus its projects? I am aware of a new class called TeamProjectPicker, but that doesn't help me. Anyone know how to select the server from this type of dialog?

Thanks,TS.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can figure it out it's more or less the same as the DomainProjectPicker.

Here's a code sample of how I was working with it:

```
    if (tpp.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
         try
         {
              //here you get the TfsTeamProjectCollection (the TeamFoundationServer class is also obsolete)
              TfsTeamProjectCollection tfsProj = tpp.SelectedTeamProjectCollection;
              //here you authenticate
              tfsProj.Authenticate();
         }
etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **TeamProjectPicker** class from Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll. There is a great blog post that describes how to wrangle the dialog: [Using the TeamProjectPicker API in TFS 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/team_foundation/archive/2010/04/20/using-the-teamprojectpicker-api-in-tfs-2010.aspx)

Here's the code sample for selecting multiple team projects:

```
Application.EnableVisualStyles(); // Makes it look nicer from a console app.

//"using" pattern is recommended as the picker needs to be disposed of
using (TeamProjectPicker tpp = new TeamProjectPicker(TeamProjectPickerMode.MultiProject, false))
{
    DialogResult result = tpp.ShowDialog();
    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Selected Team Project Collection Uri: " + tpp.SelectedTeamProjectCollection.Uri);
        System.Console.WriteLine("Selected Projects:");
        foreach(ProjectInfo projectInfo in tpp.SelectedProjects)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(projectInfo.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't care about the project and only want the user to be able to select a server and collection, use TeamProjectPickerMode.**NoProject** in the constructor.